# @click in a Vue project on the index page

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to VUE and need some help getting started.  I'm porting a JavaScript application and I need to replace the onclick event. I have loaded my index page with a menu on the left hand side and I want it to call a click event to load a vue component.

```
<ul class="lmainlist">                                   
    <li id="HOME">
        <a href="#">HOME <br><span class="leftspan"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li id="DASHBOARD">
        <a href="#">DASHBOARD <br><span class="leftspan">View all recent activity</span></a>                                       
    </li>                                  
</ul>
```

In my main.js I have

```
document.getElementById("DASHBOARD").onclick = event => {
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        components: { Dashboard},
        template: "<Dashboard/>"
    });
};
```

But I'm not sure it is getting called.  Any help is appreciated, I'm sure my code is not Vue efficient.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `onclick` function is not called.

You are only attaching a handler function to the click event.

Besides, your `<li id="DASHBOARD">` doesn't appear to be within a Vue instance. So the problem is not related to Vue.

To trigger event in pure JavaScript, use [`.dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent):

```js
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');

// This will trigger click event on `#demo` on document load
demo.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));

function clicked(){
  console.log('I am clicked');
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" onclick="clicked()">Click me</div>
```

Comment: The code that I have is on the index.html page, so it is a basic html/javascript page and I want it to call a function/method to load a vue component into the app div.  Do I call it from the same index page within the script tags?

Comment: Based on your current approach, yes, you should call it at the same page.